# MFC how to save and reuse the current device context CDC

Tags: c++, mfc

Well simply what I need to do is to create a grid of rectangle and fill any selected case of that grid at the user click. thus I save the parameters (color, position..). The problem is when I try to fill the case at the click event I can't any changes maybe because the device context is changed even if I use `GetDC()` method. So is there any way to save the current created on OnDraw() method for exmaple and use it somewhere in another function, I tried to use SaveDC() and RestoreDC() but in vain.

Here's some of my code:

```
void CXThiefManView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CXThiefManDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;
    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    //  Get the background color of the board
    COLORREF clr = pDoc->GetBoardSpace(-1, -1);
    //  Draw the background first
    pDC->FillSolidRect(&rcClient, clr);
    //  Create the brush for drawing
    CBrush br;
    br.CreateStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
    CBrush* pbrOld = pDC->SelectObject(&br);
    //  Draw the squares
    for (int row = 0; row < pDoc->GetRows(); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < pDoc->GetColumns(); col++)
        {
            //  Get the color for this board space
            clr = pDoc->GetBoardSpace(row, col);
            //  Calculate the size and position of this space
            CRect rcBlock;
            rcBlock.top = row * pDoc->GetHeight();
            rcBlock.left = col * pDoc->GetWidth();
            rcBlock.right = rcBlock.left + pDoc->GetWidth();
            rcBlock.bottom = rcBlock.top + pDoc->GetHeight();
            //  Fill in the block with the correct color
            pDC->FillSolidRect(&rcBlock, clr);
            //  Draw the block outline
            pDC->Rectangle(&rcBlock);
        }
    }

    saveState = pDC->SaveDC();

    DrawItem(pDC, pDoc->GetThiefRow(), pDoc->GetThiefCol(), pDoc->GetThiefColor());

}

void CXThiefManView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CView::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    CXThiefManDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();

    // the draw item here to fill the case
    DrawItem(GetDC(), 5, 5, RGB(0, 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Calling `GetDC` like that will cause nasty GDI resource leak. Use `CClientDC` instead. I think you want to save the painting on to a bitmap and update drawing on it? `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` is for something else.

Comment: and how can I reuse that same CClientDC in many places

Comment: You cannot save the device context retrieved in your `WM_PAINT` handler. It is recreated for every call to [BeginPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362.aspx) (this is what [CPaintDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48eab8d.aspx) does behind the covers). This device context has set up clipping to the update region. The update region generally chances from on `WM_PAINT` message to the next. Besides, you keep `br` selected into your device context, even after it is destroyed. This is the moral equivalent of a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Underneath all those MFC function, the WINAPI functions of the same name are being called. In WINAPI, `GetDC` returns a new device context. `SaveDC` & `RestoreDC` allow you to save and restore the state (brush, font etc...) of a specific DC handle, but that doesn't cross to other handles.

There's nothing MFC can do about it, nor can you. You have to reconfigure the new DC handle for your needs.

Comment: So if I understand you, I must re do all the work at the on draw function each time I need to update the context

Comment: I wanted to reconfirm my answer, so it took a while, but yes, you must reconfigure your DC each and every time, and that's what you normally do in `OnDraw`.

Answer (score 0):

Handle from `GetDC` has to be released by `ReleaseDC`. Please see [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or use `CClientDC dc(this)` which has automatic cleanup, it's usage is similar, for example `Draw(&dc,...);`.

As to your main question, you can save the drawing on a bitmap. The bitmap can be saved.

define:

```
CBitmap m_bitmap;
CDC m_memdc;
```

initialize the bitmap and dc:

```
CClientDC dc(this);
m_bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, 2000, 1200);
//this creates a bitmap as big as the screen...

m_memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
m_memdc.SelectObject(m_bitmap);
m_memdc.FillSolidRect(0, 0, 2000, 1200, RGB(255, 255, 255));
//draw on m_memdc, then draw memdc on to dc
```

Usage:

```
void CMyWindow::OnPaint()
{
    CWnd::OnPaint();
    CClientDC dc(this);

    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);

    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), &m_memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

void CMyWindow::OnMouseMove(UINT k, CPoint p)
{
    CClientDC dc(this);

    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);

    if (k & MK_LBUTTON)
    {
        //draw on m_memdc, (instead of drawing on dc)
        m_memdc.SetPixel(p.x, p.y, RGB(0,0,0));
        m_memdc.SetPixel(p.x, p.y+1, RGB(0,0,255));

        //when finished drawing, draw m_memdc on to dc
        dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), &m_memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }
}
```